# How do I prevent another user interacting while other user is providing input?

Tags: javascript

So basically, I don't want userB to write on a text field, while userA is writing on it.

More specific: I want to know how I can evade that userB starts writing in a text field while userA is writing on it, so let's say that we could add a delay between userA and userB. userA get's to write for a certain amount of time, and when that time's up, userB is able to type on the text field, and userA isn't. And so on..

I'd appreciate all your help!

Comment: pessimistic locking? But I wouldn't go that route. Just make it last in wins.

Comment: It may be easier if you generate a _GUID_ for each "change" of the field and when someone makes a change, have them post the previous _GUID_, then if it's a historical one and not the latest one, deny the change with a warning like "blah has been modified since you last saw it"

Comment: Is this some sort of collaborative document editing system, like Google Docs? It's not clear what you mean by two users writing in the same text field at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. And user2357112, we're not creating sometihng like Google Docs, we're trying to create a website where people can write stuff together, but another user will not be allowed to type at the same as the user that's typing.

Comment: CandiedOrange, thanks for your reply! I really do appreciate it! I am gonna try pessimistic locking, and to make it more secure, we want the users to fill in a captcha, so they can't spam it using a scrpit. and about the dos attacks, we can use a 3rd party company to secure it, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Most working captcha's will critically slow down your users. OCR has gotten far to good. Invest in well done ones if you go this way. My fave ask simple math questions.  Lack of a good user experience is it's own form of denial of service attack. :)

Comment: Can I ask, what is your motivation to go with pessimistic locking?

Comment: From my research, I've seen that pessimistic locking is actually a very good method to do this. It prevents another user to type at the same time as another one, just what I wanted. And I can keep doing it for different users too.

Comment: What is frustrating me is I still don't know exactly what "this" is.  Is the text typically less than 80 characters?  Help me out here.

Comment: That depends how much the user can type in 15 seconds, CandiedOrange

Answer (score 2):

```
"Pessimistic Locking prevents any other application or user from fetching or updating the same record at the same time."
```

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PessimisticLocking

```
"OptimisticLocking assumes you will be the only one changing the target. If there is a transaction conflict, the conflict could be resolved in one of several ways"
```

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?OptimisticLocking

One of the problems with the preventing approach (pessimistic locking) is userA could leave userB waiting forever.   This prevents userB from being able to work.  It might feel like you prevented them from loosing work but they did a fair bit of work deciding to edit and planning what to say.  Now you're loosing all the work that is still in their head.  Letting people say what they want to say quickly is a good way to get them invested in your process.

Last in wins (optimistic locking) creates the problem of lost data from userA, which wiki's solve by logging every change and notifying userB that their read is stale before their attempt to write is allowed to proceed. At which point userB decides to either merge, overwrite, or abandon their own change.  This motivates the client to be timely with their changes.  The advantage is that the system never stops working.  There is no waiting.  It just gets harder to make changes when you're slow or unlucky.

It's difficult to tell you which is better for you since your use case is "A text box" which could be one single word value for a single field or an entire document.  Which approach is better depends a lot on how it will get used and for what.  However, I will say that optimistic locking is a growing trend.

If you insist on pessimistic locking you could make the user experience less awful by providing more info than just locked.  You could inform userB of the time userA locked the field.  When userA last touched a key (using AJAX methods), who userA is, and how long until the system will time out userA's lock and release the field.

If this system faces the internet consider, carefully what would happen if userA doesn't have you're systems best interests at heart.  Locking and stalling would be an easy way to do a denial of service attack.

Answer (score 0):

In response to candiedorange and OP , wouldn't the use of booleans in this case be a lot more simpler, you could set a variable denoting whether the element is in use or a timestamp(easier imo) that allows the user to type for a number of seconds and once that time has run out, the boolean is false for the current user and true for the next.

Comment: Huh? You want user to decide the duration of the locks time out?  Seems very trusting to me.  I'm not even sure if you mean userA or userB.

Comment: No i'm saying there's a countdown for each user, let's say 40 seconds, after 40 seconds the boolean is false for the current user typing preventing the user from adding anything else. At the same time, userB's boolean becomes true allowing him to begin typing. The users wouldn't have any control over it.

Comment: Sounds like you're describing a mutex that get's passed around.  Whoever has the mutex gets to talk.  This would have to be supported by AJAX process.  I have seen extreme examples of this where each editing user gets their own colored carrot (cursor) on the document and can watch each other make changes key stroke by key stroke.  Changes are small and atomic so there is no waiting.